# how to write a code in javascript that conditionally loads 2 different css files?

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement

how to write a code in javascript  that conditionally loads 2 different css styles
I need to load a different css style for a page while it is loading and after it has loaded.
i.e

```
if(condition)
{load 1 css};
else 
{load another css};
```

Comment: And why would you load a different stylesheet when the page is loading, that makes no sense ?

Comment: @close voters: I disagree that this is offtopic

Answer (score 5):

You should be aware of the `<link>` tag's `disabled` feature.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" disabled="disabled" />
```

So, in your case, let us assume there are two stylesheets, `day.css` and `night.css`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="day.css" id="day" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="night.css" id="night" />
```

In your code, once you load, you can do this:

```
if (condition)
    document.getElementById('day').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

In case, you are using jQuery, it is more simpler! Use this:

```
if (condition)
{
    $("#day").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#night").prop("disabled", false);
}
else
{
    $("#day").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#night").prop("disabled", true);
}
```

Comment: you where way faster than me to point the disabled feature so +1

Comment: Ha ha... Thanks, and I also took time to edit and format the question! :P

Answer (score 0):

Alternative (jQuery based) solution:

```
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if (YOUR_CONDITION) {
        $(document.head).append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">');
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
</body>
```

### [Live demo](http://codepen.io/albertmatyi/pen/miGzI)

Compared to the `disabled` based solutions this only loads one `CSS`.

Answer (score -1):

Please use dynamic insertion of CSS file. refer code below.

```
function loadcssfile(filename){
    var fileref=document.createElement("link");
    fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
    }
    if(condition1)
        loadcssfile("mystyle1.css") ////dynamically load and add this .css file
    else if(condition2)
        loadcssfile("mystyle2.css") ////dynamically load and add this .css file`
```

Comment: Hi, using code you haven't written yourself without attribution isn't encouraged on Stack Overflow.